# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'bar'

Tags: python, numpy, plot, seaborn, attributeerror

I wrote this code, but it gives me an AttributeError saying that the plot doesn't have `bar`. How can I fix it?

```
import seaborn as sns

fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(25, 7.5), dpi=100)
fig.suptitle(f'Counts of Observation Labels in ciciot_2023 ', fontsize=25)
sns.countplot(x="class_label", palette="OrRd_r", data=dataset, order=dataset['class_label'].value_counts().index, ax=ax1)

ax1.set_title('ciciot2023', fontsize=20)
ax1.set_xlabel('label', fontsize=15)
ax1.set_ylabel('count', fontsize=15)
ax1.tick_params(labelrotation=90)

plt.show()
```

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-685308b57f2d> in <cell line: 4>()
      2 fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(25, 7.5), dpi=100)
      3 fig.suptitle(f'Counts of Observation Labels in ciciot_2023 ', fontsize=25)
----> 4 sns.countplot(x="class_label", palette="OrRd_r",  data=dataset,  order=dataset['class_label'].value_counts().index, ax=ax1)
      5 
      6 ax1.set_title('ciciot2023', fontsize=20)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/seaborn/categorical.py in draw_bars(self, ax, kws)
   1543         """Draw the bars onto `ax`."""
   1544         # Get the right matplotlib function depending on the orientation
-> 1545         barfunc = ax.bar if self.orient == "v" else ax.barh
   1546         barpos = np.arange(len(self.statistic))
   1547 

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'bar'
```

Comment: What is `dataset`? Can you give an inline short example of dataset that causese this error?

Comment: Please include the full traceback, even if it's obvious that the error originates in countplot.

Comment: The argument for the `order` parameter should be a list of strings (see the documentation); `dataset['class_label'].value_counts().index` is possibly not a list of strings (or equivalent); please double check.

Comment: check the idenrity of `ax1` created in line 2.  That's passed to the seaborn function as `ax`

Comment: We need code that can be run. Please read [mre] and edit your question. It will help us help you, ***and*** help you develop your coding skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In
`fig,(ax1)= plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(25, 7.5), dpi=100)`,
`ax1` is an array of axes (since you created two columns). Perhaps you tried to unpack it, by using the `(ax1)` syntax, but that does nothing here: these are just parentheses around a variable name.

Instead, try

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(25, 7.5), dpi=100)
```

to get your two axes.

Comment: In case you do need to unpack a single-item tuple, use `fig, (ax1,) =`.

Comment: thanks! I can fix it. I plot one ax and I set  _plt.subplots(ncols=2)_ and this was incorrect. **ncols** parameter should  set 1 for one plot.

Comment: @hanie Indeed, that's a different fix (but quite different, since it goes from two plots to one plot) for the same problem.

Comment: @9769953 yeah,I understand. I need just  one plot.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the issue here is that in `ax=ax1`, `ax1` is an array of "AxesSubplots" since you defined `ncols=2` in `plt.subplots`. Try using the first position of the array `ax1[0]` like this:

```
sns.countplot(x="class_label", palette="OrRd_r",  data=dataset,  order=dataset['class_label'].value_counts().index, ax=ax1[0])
```